Test for prometheus alert rule does nor work
I want to write prometheus test for an alert rule that would be work if failed requests to application is above 2 for 5 minutes.
Alert:
- alert: app_failed_requests
  expr: sum(increase(synonymous_failed_events_total[5m])) + sum(increase(semantic_failed_events_total[5m])) > 2
  for: 5m
  labels:
    severity: warning
    side: "back"
  annotations:
    summary: "requests are failed"


Test:
rule_files:
  - ../alert-rules.yaml

tests:
  - interval: 30s
    input_series:
      - series: 'synonymous_failed_events_total'
        values: '1 1x30'
      - series: 'semantic_failed_events_total'
        values: '1 1x30'

    alert_rule_test:
      - eval_time: 5m
        alertname: app_failed_requests
        exp_alerts:
          - exp_labels:
              severity: warning
              side: back
            exp_annotations:
              summary: "requests are failed"


But this test does not work
Unit Testing:  ./charts/app/prometheus/tests/app_failed_requests.yaml
  FAILED:
    alertname: app_failed_requests, time:5m, 
        exp:"[Labels:{alertname=\"app_failed_requests\", severity=\"warning\", side=\"back\"} Annotations:{summary=\"requests are failed\"}]"

